# ExpressJS Redirect And Return Data For Request

Tags: node.js, express

Say I'm going to redirect from `/1` to `/2`. Obviously I can just redirect, and have the browser send a separate request to `/2`.

Is there a way that I can call `res.location('/2')` and then return the data from that url as if the request to that url was a GET request?

Thanks!

Edit: The redirect from 1 to 2 will happen on a validated POST from 1, which can either fail, going back to 1, or succeed, redirecting to 2. What I want is something like

```
app.post('/2', function(req, res) {
    if (validate(req.body) {
        res.location('2');
        res.send(app.getResponseFor('1'));
    } else {
        res.render('2');
    }
});
```

I think one way to do this is to rip the function out of 1, and just have both 1 and 2 call into it. Maybe someone can think of a more elegant way!

Answer (score 0):

That's more like a "design issue". You could implement this in two ways:

With smart client:

- The client requests for the `/2` resource in ajax mode,
- The server responds with a 4xx code (eg 401 for unauthorised)
- The client catches this exception (error case) and requests the resource from `/1` without redirecting the user

With Helpers in server side:

- You split your application logic in a classic MVC architecture,
- The controllers of `/2` endpoint use some helper functions so they can check the condition of the request
- If the request doesn't follow some certain rules, a helper function provide the controller with the appropriate content, as if the client had requested the `/1` endpoint

Hope this helps.

Cheers.